# LinkedIn login with custom token ( ERROR_INVALID_CUSTOM_TOKEN )

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to login with LinkedIn using the native app and the LinkedIn SDK. So far I can login using the web if the LinkedIn app is not installed. I can also login with LinkedIn and get a token in return. But when I try to authenticate with Firebase I get this error:

```
Optional(Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17000 "The custom token 
format is incorrect. Please check the documentation." UserInfo=
{NSLocalizedDescription=The custom token format is incorrect. Please 
check the documentation., error_name=ERROR_INVALID_CUSTOM_TOKEN})
```

This is my code:

```
        // App installed
        let permissions = [LISDK_BASIC_PROFILE_PERMISSION,LISDK_EMAILADDRESS_PERMISSION]

        LISDKSessionManager.createSession(withAuth: permissions, state: nil, showGoToAppStoreDialog: true, successBlock: { (returnState) -> Void in
            LISDKAPIHelper.sharedInstance().getRequest("https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,email-address,picture-url,public-profile-url,industry,positions,location)?format=json", success: { (response) -> Void in

                if let data = response?.data.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
                   if let dictResponse = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers){

                        let token = LISDKSessionManager.sharedInstance().session.accessToken.accessTokenValue

                        Auth.auth().signIn(withCustomToken: token!  ) { (user, error) in
                            print(user!)
                            print(error!)
                        }
                    }
                }

            }, error: { (error) -> Void in
                print("LINKEDIN error\(String(describing: error))")

            })

        }) { (error) -> Void in
            print("error login linkedin")
        }
```

The token I am sending to Firebase is a String, so that should be okay. I must be missing something. But what ?

Comment: How are you minting the custom token?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my misunderstanding. I thought I could use the Linkedin token directly. It has to go to a webservice that uses the Firebase admin user to generate the token.